# How to make this code shorter? Text - to - speech in C# button

Tags: c#, button, text-to-speech

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace voicebutton
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            speaker.Speak("A as in apple");
            speaker.Rate = -2;
            speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);

        }
    }
}
```

I was making a program where when you click a button it will play a sound.
My problem is that I will have 26 buttons and I have to set its rate and gender one by one. Is there a way for me to make it short.
I tried to make classes but it won't work.Can anyone help me or knows a tutorial for this in the net. I search some but won't fit to what I need.

And also I tried to change my voice gender to female(as you can see above code) but when I clicked it at the first time it will play a male voice but after the second clicked it will play to female. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *1)* Keep configurations in a single point like a `List<MyClass>` or a `List<Tuple<string, int , VoiceGender>>`.  *2)* Assign an index to each button (for example assign an index to `Tag`, or use a naming convention, or keep list of buttons in a `List<Button>` and find index of a button using `buttonsList.IndexOf(someButton)`. *3)* Handle `Click` event of all buttons using the same event handler method and speak. In this method you can get index of the button which is boxed in `sender`, so you can extract configurations from the list and speak using extracted configurations.

Comment: @RezaAghaei why don't you post it as an answer instead? You don't get any rep from comments and it's hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can set one event (like your `button1_Click`) to each one of the buttons, and then use the `sender` property to determine further actions like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> soundDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>();

private static void LoadDictionary()
{
    soundDictionary.Add("a", "A as in apple.");
    soundDictionary.Add("b", "B as in banana.");
}

private void PlaySound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var letter = button.Tag;

    speaker.Rate = -2;
    speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
    speaker.Speak(dictionary[letter]);
}
```

Make sure you call the `LoadDictionary()` method before the `PlaySound_Click` events.

And for your speaker gender, you could try setting the gender before the `Speak()` method like here:

```
speaker.Rate = -2;
speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
speaker.Speak("A as in apple");
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I could guess the question will be closed as off-topic or something else, so I just tried to guide the user to the correct direction. Feel free to use any part of my comment if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same function for every button and make a

```
string buttonName = ((Button)sender).Name;
string speechText = string.Empty;
if (buttonName == "Button1"))
{ 
  speechText = "A as in apple";
} else if
...
speaker.Speak(speechText );
speaker.Rate = -2;
speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
```

You can even improve it if you use a `Dictionary<string,string>` or even `Dictionary<Control,string>`

Like this:

```
//in Form.Designer.cs
public partial class Form1 {
  private InitializeComponent() {
    //Code of the Designer
    this.button1.Text = "My Fancy Button";
    this.button1.Click += this.button_click;
    //Code of the Designer
    this.button2.Text = "My Other Fancy Button";
    this.button2.Click += this.button_click;
    //Code of the Designer
  }
}

//in Form.cs
public class Form1 : Form {
  //Constructor
  public Form1 () {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.SetupSpeechTexts();
  }

  private Dictonary<Control, string> speechTextDict = new Dictonary<Control, string>();

  private void SetupSpeechTexts() {
    this.speechTextDict.Add(this.button1, "First Text");
    this.speechTextDict.Add(this.button2, "Second Text");
    ...
  }

  private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Control senderControl = (Control)sender;
    if(this.speechTextDict.ContainsKey(senderControl)) {
      speaker.Speak(this.speechTextDict[senderControl]);
      speaker.Rate = -2;
      speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry because I'm a beginner. Can you explain to me where should I put each code? and what do I have to input inside my button?

Comment: both in your `Form1.cs`. If you use the Visual Studio Designer you can select in the Events Tab for your Control the Click Event there you select `button_click`. Witout Designer you have somewhere the code that instances your Controls (like psotion and Text and that stuff) there you can add `this.buttonXYZ.Click  += this.button_click;`. this adds you Function to the Event of the control so it gets called if you click on a Button for example. In your contructor you add the call to `this.SetupSpeechText()`

Comment: Added the code int my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The gender voice issue came since you call speak method and after that you apply the female gender configuration.
So to a void this issue you should just put the configuration and then call speak method as below:

```
  speaker.Rate = -2;
  speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
  speaker.Speak("A as in apple");
```

And to make the code shorter first thing you should make a method that take Text and Gender and it will execute the speak thing, something like below

```
public void speak(String toSpeak, VoiceGender gender){
   SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
   speaker.Rate = -2;
   speaker.SelectVoiceByHints(gender);
   speaker.Speak(toSpeak );
}
```

And you could use if statement to check which button is raising this event as madddin mentioned in his answer, and then just call this above function.